# How do I make a button in java correspond with a textField?

Tags: java, calculator, textfield

Just finished my first year of university and wanted to improve my coding skills in Java. I'm currently trying to develop a simple GUI calculator application. However, I'm stuck on how I would make on my of my jButtons such as the number one appear on my textfield once pressed. I understand I will probably have to use an action listener for this function but I'm currently stuck. 
Any help would be amazing. Thank you very much.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("F:\\Java Summer Project\\Sumer_Project\\images\\farme_image.jpg").getImage());
    frame.setSize(500, 480);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    ////// panel\\\
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    frame.add(panel);

    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 200);
    textField.setEnabled(true);
    panel.add(textField);

    JButton openbracketButton = new JButton("(");
    openbracketButton.setBounds(0, 200, 50, 50);
    panel.add(openbracketButton);

    JButton closebracketButton = new JButton(")");
    closebracketButton.setBounds(50, 200, 50, 50);
    panel.add(closebracketButton);

    JButton percButton = new JButton("%");
    percButton.setBounds(100, 200, 50, 50);
    panel.add(percButton);

    JButton clearButton = new JButton("ac");
    clearButton.setBounds(150, 200, 50, 50);
    panel.add(clearButton);

    JButton divideButton = new JButton("÷");
    divideButton.setBounds(150, 250, 50, 50);
    panel.add(divideButton);

    JButton timesButton = new JButton("X");
    timesButton.setBounds(150, 300, 50, 50);
    panel.add(timesButton);

    JButton minusButton = new JButton("+");
    minusButton.setBounds(150, 350, 50, 50);
    panel.add(minusButton);

    JButton plusButton = new JButton("-");
    plusButton.setBounds(150, 400, 50, 50);
    panel.add(plusButton);

    JButton oneButton = new JButton("1");
    oneButton.setBounds(0, 250, 50, 50);
    oneButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent oneButton) {
            System.out.println("Do Something Clicked");
        }
    });

    panel.add(oneButton);
```

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/package-summary.html) where it is explained how to change text and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
oneButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent oneButton) {
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(textField)) {
            // If its empty so just put 1 in the display
            textField.setText("1");
        } else {
            // Get value on display and convert to a integer
            // Plus one because its the button one
            int result = 1 + Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
            // Set the result to the display
            textField.setText((String) result);
        }
    }
});
```

Good luck on your studies!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a pressed action to your number buttons and set the textFields text to the desired text.(Or append if necessary).

```
// Like this
textField.setText("1");
```

And I really recommend you the Eclipse Window Builder if you are going to use java Gui. It would save you a lot of time with some Gui codes that would never increase your Java knowledge. If you really want to increase your Java knowledge, you can check this book out:

Data Structures and Algorithms in Java 6e
Michael T. Goodrich , Roberto Tamassia , Michael H. Goldwasser